# Some scripts have compilation errors which may prevent obsolete API usages to get updated. Obsolete API updating will continue automatically after

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just installed Ubuntu 19.4. and installed the Linux Hub from here

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-v-1-6-0-is-now-available.640792/

After installing the Unity Hub I installed the version 2019.2.0b2 (Personal) and I get this message after creating a new fresh project

> Some scripts have compilation errors which may prevent obsolete API
>   usages to get updated. Obsolete API updating will continue
>   automatically after these errors get fixed.

So after creating the project and lauching the editor the console shows these messages

[image]

Unfortunately the error messages are empty. I tried to install the versions

- 2019.3.0a2
- 2019.2.0b2
- 2019.1.3f1

but still get the same errors. I am not able to run the project because of these errors. How can I fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working! All I did was executing this in the terminal

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

I got it from here

https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/issues/252

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the same problem and what "Question3r" said works with me too:

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

then

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```